# How to define a constant size for specific Cells in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to keep a constant size for all Rows and Columns of a DataGridView.

[image: DataGridView]

This is the code I'm using:

```
table.Columns.Add("SR.NO", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("CLASS", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ROLL NO", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("GR.NO", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ADHAAR CARD UID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("GENDER", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("CONTACT", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ADDRESS", typeof(int));
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Columns can be made so they cannot be resized, not sure of rows.  But...but...Name and Address as Int?  Very hardcore

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp lol...I just copy pasted the first one and later changed it but got a doubt though I knew to change the types. So what can I do to make them size as I want isnt there any code for it?

Comment: What do you mean by constant size? Can you demonstrate the issue with the current grid layout?

Comment: @defaultlocale I want the First column for SR.NO to be abit small horizontally and the name Column to be big and same for the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick demo project, showing how to use **RowTemplate** property to disable row resizing (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate?view=netframework-4.8)).

```
public partial class frmDataGridView : Form
{
    public frmDataGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmDataGridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // disable resizing of rows
        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;

        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 75; // set to preferred (your personal) default

        // datasource - structure
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("SR.NO", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("CLASS", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("ROLL NO", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("GR.NO", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("ADHAAR CARD UID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("GENDER", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("CONTACT", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("ADDRESS", typeof(int));

        // datasource - data
        table.Rows.Add(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 40; // set a specific width for first column in DataGridView
    }
}
```

This would result in a form with a datagridview like this:

[image: DataGridView fixed row height]

You can set Width property for every column you want (see [DataGridViewColumn.Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_Width)).

Comment: Can't I define the size of the Column individually? for eg. the SR.NO Column to be small horizontally but the NAME Column to be big and same applies to the other Columns

Comment: you can set width for every datagridviewcolumn you want - see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can specify whether users can resize Columns and Rows, setting the [AllowUserToResizeColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoresizecolumns) and [AllowUserToResizeRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoresizerows) properties:

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
```

You also need to disable the automatic Column resize feature ([AutoResizeColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumns) property), so you can specify a custom measure:

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None);
dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

Disable the [wrap mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode) of both Columns and Rows:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
```

Set the [RowTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate) to some specific values; this style is used when no other style is specified. It's quite useful to prevent the grid from changing its styles (and, possibly, layout) when the host Form changes its own styles:
(Both the Font and the cells' `ForeColor` and `BackColor` are important)

```
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font = 
    new Font("Segoe UI", 9.25f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
```

You can determine the height of the Rows, if you need a specific one. Take care that the Row height cannot be set to the exact size of the Font, otherwise controls as the CheckBox and the ComboBox won't fit and will not be drawn.
Here, I'm using the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) method to measure a string using the Font set in **`RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font`**.

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 40;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = TextRenderer.MeasureText(
    "Sample Text", dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font).Height + 4;
```

Since the wrap mode is disabled, you could just use the [AutoSizeRowsMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode), setting it to **`DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`**.

Now, after setting the **`DataGridView.DataSource`**, you can also set the width of all the Columns to the same value (or any other custom value):
(Here, the Width of all Columns is set to `150` pixels)

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = [DataTable];
dataGridView1.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.Width = 150);
```